# Angular not run directive

Tags: angularjs

Why is that when I run my Angular app, I don't get directive running?

Example code:

```
var app = angular.module("app",['mgcrea.ngStrap','layout.menu']);

app.controller('MainController', ['$scope','$timeout', function($scope,$timeout){
    $timeout(function(){console.log("ready")});
}]);

var menu = angular.module('layout.menu', [])

.controller('MenuController', ['$scope', function($scope){
    console.log("controller");
}])

.directive('menuDir', ['$window', function($window){
    console.log("directive");
    return function (scope, element) {
         console.log("return directive");
    };
}]);
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="app">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/libs/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="assets/libs/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/libs/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/libs/angular-strap/dist/angular-strap.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/libs/angular-strap/dist/angular-strap.tpl.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="MainController">
    <div class="list-group mainmenu" id="mainmenu" ng-controller="MenuController"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

When I run the app, I get the `controller` output, but no output from directive. Why? How can I fix it?

Comment: @m59 I have updated the question with HTML.

Comment: where in your markup are you using menuDir directive?

Comment: @VinayK What I am trying to do is to put window resize detection into directive. I followed a simple version here http://jsfiddle.net/jaredwilli/SfJ8c/ and it works. How can I put it into my project?

Comment: add `menu-dir` atribute to #mainmenu div(or any other)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Directives/Services/Factories in angularJs are lazily instantiated.

They will be processed only when we use them.

Use the `menuDir` directive in your markup, then you will see the console statement written inside your directive.